# How to combine 2 rows in 1

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to reshape a data frame but I'm totally lost in how to proceed:

```
    > test
  #                Time Entry Order Size   Price  S / L   T / P Profit Balance
1 1 2017-01-11 00:00:00   buy     1 0.16 1.05403 1.0449 1.07838     NA      NA
2 3 2017-01-24 16:00:00   s/l     1 0.16 1.04490 1.0449 1.07838 -97.28 9902.72
```

As you can see, we have 2 (or more) registers for one order ID. What I want to do is combine those 2 rows into one by adding several new columns: Exit (that's where the "s/l" entry of the second observation should go), Exit Price (there should go the data for the Price column on the second entry) and replace the NA from the first entry with the data of the second one on the Profit and Balance columns.

By the way, the original name of the Entry column is "Type" but I already changed that, so that's why it doesn't make that much sense of having the exit reason of the trade on a column called "Entry". So far I've only thought of extracting the data on several vectors and then just do a mutate on the first entry and dropping the second one, but I'm quite sure there's a better way of doing that. Also, that stone-age approach would be useless when applied to the whole data frame.

If possible, I'd like to stick to the tidyverse library to do this just for ease of replication. Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Can you show your expected output for the given example? Also it would be helpful if you could include few more rows in your sample and share the data with `dput`.

Comment: Just managed to sort it out, I split the data into 2 separate data frames, reshaped them and then full joined them, I'll post the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sorting it out! My solution was to split the data frame in 2, reshape each half as needed, and then full joining them. Here's the initial data frame:

```
    > head(backtest_table, n = 10)
    #             Time  Type Order Size   Price   S / L   T / P Profit  Balance
1   1 2017.01.11 00:00   buy     1 0.16 1.05403 1.04490 1.07838     NA       NA
2   2 2017.01.19 00:00   buy     2 0.16 1.05376 1.04480 1.07764     NA       NA
3   3 2017.01.24 16:00   s/l     1 0.16 1.04490 1.04490 1.07838 -97.28  9902.72
4   4 2017.01.24 16:00   s/l     2 0.16 1.04480 1.04480 1.07764 -95.48  9807.24
5   5 2017.02.09 00:00   buy     3 0.15 1.05218 1.04265 1.07758     NA       NA
6   6 2017.03.03 16:00   t/p     3 0.15 1.07758 1.04265 1.07758 251.75 10058.99
7   7 2017.03.29 00:00   buy     4 0.15 1.08826 1.07859 1.11405     NA       NA
8   8 2017.04.04 00:00 close     4 0.15 1.08416 1.07859 1.11405 -41.24 10017.75
9   9 2017.04.04 00:00  sell     5 0.15 1.08416 1.09421 1.05737     NA       NA
10 10 2017.04.07 00:00  sell     6 0.15 1.08250 1.09199 1.05718     NA       NA
```

Here's the code I used to modify everything:

```
    # Re-format data
library(lubridate)

# Separate entries and exits
entries <- backtest_table %>% filter(Type %in% c("buy", "sell"))
exits <- backtest_table %>% filter(!Type %in% c("buy", "sell"))

# Reshape entries and exits

# Entries
 entries <- entries[-c(1, 9, 10)]

 colnames(entries) <- c("Entry time", "Entry type", "Order", "Entry volume", 
                        "Entry price", "Entry SL", "Entry TP")

 entries$`Entry time` <- entries$`Entry time` %>% ymd_hm()
 entries$`Entry type` <- as.factor(entries$`Entry type`)

# Exits
 exits <- exits[-1]

 colnames(exits) <- c("Exit time", "Exit type", "Order", "Exit volume",
                      "Exit price", "Exit SL", "Exit TP", "Profit", "Balance")

 exits$`Exit time` <- exits$`Exit time` %>% ymd_hm()
 exits$`Exit type` <- as.factor(exits$`Exit type`)

# Join re-shaped data
 test <- full_join(entries, exits, by = c("Order"))
```

And here's the output of that:

```
>  head(test, n = 10)
   Entry time Entry type Order Entry volume Entry price Entry SL Entry TP           Exit time
1  2017-01-11        buy     1         0.16     1.05403  1.04490  1.07838 2017-01-24 16:00:00
2  2017-01-19        buy     2         0.16     1.05376  1.04480  1.07764 2017-01-24 16:00:00
3  2017-02-09        buy     3         0.15     1.05218  1.04265  1.07758 2017-03-03 16:00:00
4  2017-03-29        buy     4         0.15     1.08826  1.07859  1.11405 2017-04-04 00:00:00
5  2017-04-04       sell     5         0.15     1.08416  1.09421  1.05737 2017-05-26 10:00:00
6  2017-04-07       sell     6         0.15     1.08250  1.09199  1.05718 2017-05-01 09:20:00
7  2017-04-19       sell     7         0.15     1.07334  1.08309  1.04733 2017-04-25 10:00:00
8  2017-05-05       sell     8         0.14     1.07769  1.08773  1.05093 2017-05-29 14:00:00
9  2017-05-24       sell     9         0.14     1.06673  1.07749  1.03803 2017-06-22 18:00:00
10 2017-06-14       sell    10         0.14     1.04362  1.05439  1.01489 2017-06-15 06:40:00
   Exit type Exit volume Exit price Exit SL Exit TP  Profit  Balance
1        s/l        0.16    1.04490 1.04490 1.07838  -97.28  9902.72
2        s/l        0.16    1.04480 1.04480 1.07764  -95.48  9807.24
3        t/p        0.15    1.07758 1.04265 1.07758  251.75 10058.99
4      close        0.15    1.08416 1.07859 1.11405  -41.24 10017.75
5        t/p        0.15    1.05737 1.09421 1.05737  265.58 10091.18
6        s/l        0.15    1.09199 1.09199 1.05718  -94.79  9825.60
7        s/l        0.15    1.08309 1.08309 1.04733  -97.36  9920.39
8        t/p        0.14    1.05093 1.08773 1.05093  247.61 10338.79
9        t/p        0.14    1.03803 1.07749 1.03803  265.59 10504.05
10       s/l        0.14    1.05439 1.05439 1.01489 -100.33 10238.46
```

And that combined the observations where a trade was added that showed NAs on the last columns with the observations where that trade was closed, populating the last columns with the actual result and new account balance!

If someone has suggestions on how to improve the system please let me know!